# How should be the correct http request url in flutter to fetch data from the shopify store?

Tags: flutter, http, dart, url, shopify

1. How should be the correct HTTP request URL in a flutter to fetch data from the Shopify store?
2. Any idea or material, how to integrate payment method with Shopify in a flutter when the user clicks the buy button?

I am trying with this line for HTTP requests, but not working

```
getUserData() async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.https(
      '{apikey}:{password}@{hostname}.myshopify.com',
      '/admin/api/{version}/{resource}.json'));
  var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(jsonData);
}

  getUserData() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.https(
        'c948656b86f9a9e0bf8beffad653e484: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@verdenapp310.myshopify.com',
        '/admin/api/2021-07/graphql.json'));
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(jsonData);
  }
```

print output: I/flutter (31610): {errors: Not Found}

Comment: Are you getting any error logs?

Comment: I/flutter (31610): {errors: Not Found}

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to do some work. Study the architecture of the Shopify platform and then decide the correct API to use. In your brief example, you are choosing the Admin API, which is completely wrong for retrieving data from a store, unless you are an App installed in the store, to benefit the merchant experience. Usually, Admin API has nothing to do with customers.

Buy Button has a direct line to Shopify checkout. You do not get to install your own payment gateway through that button. The merchant has to select or install the payment gateway they want to use from their Shop. Note that it is possible to provide for custom payment gateways in Shopify but that is far outside the scope of your SO request here. Again, they have documentation for that too.